# Php-fpm corrupts my socket permission on startup

Tags: apache-2.2, permissions, php-fpm, fastcgi, socket

I've installed Apache2.2 with FastCgi module, and PHP-fpm on a Centos server.

I configure FastCgi with an external server using the socket option:

```
FastCgiExternalServer /var/www/cgi-bin/test/php.fcgi -socket /var/run/php5-fpm.sock -pass-header Authorization -idle-timeout 3600
```

When I start my services (httpd and php-fpm) I got an error 500 when I request my helloWorld-test-page. But if I add write access to every user on my `php5-fpm.sock` file my hello world page works fine ! So I thought it's the good configuration...

But as soon as php-fpm service restart I saw my socket's permissions automatically updated and then my test-page doesn't works anymore:

```
srw-rw----   1 root   root      0 Nov  9 23:30 php5-fpm.sock
```

What is the good configuration for a socket file, and do you know what I should configure to make it definitive?